# Getting structured text from multiple classes

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

Working on a **scraper** using node and the cheerio library and have a basic question. The site that is being **scraped** has a structure that is similar to the following:

```
<article class="featured h-event">
  // Lots of irrelevant stuff
  <div class="p-name">name goes here</div>
  // Lots of irrelevant stuff
    <div class="p-location">location</div>
  // Lots of irrelevant stuff
</article>
```

I am using cheerio, which a logic similar to jquery, and using the following code:

```
var items = $(".featured.h-event")
  .map(function (i, el) {
    var x = cheerio.load(el)
    return { name: x(".p-name").text(), location: x(".p-location").text() }
    })
  .get()
```

This works, but it feels there should be an easier/faster way to accomplish what I am trying to do. I am uncomfortable with the `var x`line, which is probably wasting resources. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, we're using a little less code but the result should be similar:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

let html = 
`<article class="featured h-event">
<!-- Lots of irrelevant stuff -->
<div class="p-name">name goes here</div>
<!-- Lots of irrelevant stuff -->
<div class="p-location">location</div>
</article>
<article class="featured h-event">
    <!-- Lots of irrelevant stuff -->
    <div class="p-name">name goes here #2</div>
    <!-- Lots of irrelevant stuff -->
    <div class="p-location">location #2</div>
</article>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);

const resultList = $(".featured.h-event").map((i, elem) =>  {
    return { name: $(".p-name", elem).text(), location: $(".p-location", elem).text()};
}).get();

console.log(resultList);
```